# about the Plugin of Atom Editor

Tags: javascript, html, editor, atom-editor

I'm testing a new text editor, [GitHub's Atom Editor](https://atom.io), I'm writing `HTML`, so I want to open `.html` files in browser just like in Sublime Text 2/3 then I installed a package called [`run-in-browser`](https://atom.io/packages/run-in-browser).

I cannot get it to work, it will open one of my `.html` files, any other `.html` file doesn't open. Then, I changed to another package called [`open-in-browser`](https://atom.io/packages/open-in-browser). It seems to have the same issue!

Comment: Hi @laoquiren - Welcome to Stack Overflow, I get the impression that you have a problem with an Atom Plugin however your question is not entirely clear to me could you have a read of [ask] then [edit] your question to be clear about exactly which plugin you are having trouble with (include a link), what is actually happening and what you are expecting to happen - screenshots would be ideal.

Comment: Thanks a lot,my problem is that the 'run-in-browser' package which can help me open a html file in browser doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a bit of a play with the [open-in-browser](https://atom.io/packages/open-in-browser) package, by creating a very simple test case I have created two files, `test1.html` and `test2.html`, by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> keyboard shortcut I am able to get both files to open up in Chrome:

[image: Screenshot of open-in-browser]

All of this said I strongly recommend taking a look at [Live Reload](http://livereload.com/) and the associated [Atom Package](https://atom.io/packages/livereload), it takes a little bit of time to get everything setup but once it is done you will never need to open new tabs or hit the reload button.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how interesting, why mine does not work? Will is it because that some other package of my atom are not fixed with this 'run-in-browser' package? Thank you again!

Comment: And thank you for helping me edit my question's grammar, my English is poor, it's you make my question clearer.